# How to print a variable's name in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I need to inform the user of my Makefile about he must set an environment variable.

```
target: dependency
    @if test ! -f $(FILE) ; then\
        echo Vitally needed $(FILE) is missed. ;\
        echo You can change the path to the file by setting $(get_var_name $(FILE)) environment variable.;\
    fi
```

So, is there a way to obtain the name of $(FILE) (what I've called $(get_var_name ...) make function) so that the user would see the following output?

```
Vitally needed very.very.important.file is missed.
You can change the path to the file by setting FILE environment variable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
target: dependency
    @if test ! -f $(FILE) ; then\
        echo Vitally needed $(FILE) is missed. ;\
        echo You can change the path to the file by setting FILE environment variable.;\
    fi
```

Because the name of the FILE variable is FILE.

Comment: And what if I change the variable name?

Comment: @krokoziabla When you change a name of a variable, you must change the name at all places where you use it. This is no different.

Comment: Indeed. I had a party yesterday. :-) Thanks